# Remove doubling of icon when ruuning on device

Tags: android, icons, android-icons

i'm getting an issue while running app on a device like two icons are displaying on screen instead of one. My all code is correct ng bu and app is running correctly but getting this sort of problem!. 
Anyone knows please help me out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml and find activities with android.intent.category.LAUNCHER category. For each such activity there is an icon on launcher.

```
    <activity android:name="com.example.MyActivity" 
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks a bundle smile emoticon

Answer (score 2):

Your manifest file should only have intent filter category line  in the activity you want to have an icon:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.MAIN" />
```